# splice function not removing 2 cosecutive string from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function filter_list(l) {
    l.map((item,i,main) => {
     if(typeof item==="string")
     {return main.splice(i,1);}
      else
      return item;
    });
  console.log(l);
}
filter_list([1,'a','b','c',0,15,'k','e']);
```

here i am expecting output of `[1, 0, 15]`. But instead it is giving me `[1, "b", 0, 15, "e"]`. it seems to not removing strings one exists after another. Also i am trying to get the updated array in a new array variable but i don't have any idea how to do that here.  Some help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove all strings?

Comment: yes exactly. but with map

Comment: Curious, why do you want to use `map`?

Comment: i know is unethical but honestly im just trying to understand how this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that when you splice element from original array you get problem in iteration of `map()`, so for example when you remove `a` with index of 1 now the next element with index of 2 is `c` because original array is now this `[ 1, "b", "c", 0, 15, "k", "e" ]` so you skip `b`. If you don't remove elements you can see that map will match not numbers in your code.

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  l.map((item, i, main) => {
    if (typeof item == "string") main[i] = null
  })
  return l;
}

console.log(filter_list([1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 15, 'k', 'e']))
```

Comment: How does map work when the array it's working on keeps changing its length?

Comment: It doesn't `:)`.

Comment: i get the idea. lets say i don't touch the main array and the how i can set this to another variable ?

Comment: I think i understand what you are asking, so arrays are passed by reference so if your function just returns original modified array and you put value of that function in new variable its still same array as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1731/, but you can create copy of array and there are couple methods to do that one is using `slice()` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1732/

Comment: Also note that when you use map it returns new array https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1733/

Comment: basically i want to know how can i get `[1, 0, 15]` instead of `[1, null, null, null, 0, 15, null, null]`

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use the `filter` function and return `true` for everything that's not a `string`.

```
var a = [1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 15, 'k', 'e'];
var b = a.filter(function (item) {
    return ! (typeof item === 'string');
});
```

Comment: OP mentions consecutive, but his desired output is achieved using the above solution.